# How i may develop in php and html?

Tags: php, html

I am learning php from the internet on codeacademy.com. I have also learned html and css but the problem that i dont know how can i build a complete website then !

I study everything on its side. But how to put all my knowledge together its very hard! like when should i use this php code? When should i use the html code? So that i can make a full website.

Comment: **Since you've already started learning this should be easy for you.  Follow a few tutorials/video tutorials and you should have the hang of things in no time.  I'm going to share a few links with you:** http://tutvid.com/create-a-full-css-webpage-dreamweaver-tutorial/ and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iIqg9OeQRK0 and tutsplus.com and lots of youtube tutorials are helpful too.  Good luck

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> like when should i use this php code? and when i should use that html code etc.

You would need first to **understand** the concept of server-side technology(C#, java, Php, et..) and client-side technology (HTML, CSS, JS, etc..). The good source of learning is starting with a good **book** of web-development. Jumping from one video tutorial to another will not help.

Basic terminology on web development could be [**found here**](http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/client-server.php),
and a related SE discussion on thus terminology could be found [**here**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/171203/57164).

Here is a good SE [**question and discussion**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/208936/57164) on this topic.

Comment: You certainly don't need a book to learn web design/web development.  I taught myself everything that this guy has learned when I was 12.  I'm definitely an advocate of books, but for this it would be a little bit of overkill.  All of that information is available for free on the internet.  He's not asking how to learn PHP or HTML, he's asking how to apply it.  He understands the concepts.  He should probably follow a few tutorials online to build some basic websites and get the hang of 'why/when to use what and how/where'

Comment: A well written book or tutorial, does not matter. The essence of answer is to follow some guidelines that teaches fundamentals first.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is used for semantically formatting (structuring) the data that you get from PHP (or any other such backend...), to put it very simply. CSS is used to change how the HTML looks. JS can be used to do special graphical effects or simple data processing (remove things after clicking, and so on) with the HTML.